# Binding data in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, gson

I have following scenario. There is OrderHeader and OrderDetail tables in SQLLite database. I have Activity where I want to display that data. There is number of fields...

The way I see it - it has to be like this:

1. Get data from my content provider (I have it).
2. Get ordinals for columns in cursor.
3. Get values from cursor and format/assign them

Like I said - there is MANY fields and writing this kind of code (especially #1 and #2) very tedious and boring :)

So, I've got this idea.. Since my data comes in as JSON to begin with (from web) - I can store original JSON presentation in database along with parsed-out data and when I need to bind - all I need is to query table for this column and deserialize with GSON. This way - #1 and #2 will be 3 lines instead of many. And I will work with POJO...

Does that sounds good or there is natural nice way to bind views to data from database?

Answer (score 0):

Use a ListView and a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) (or extend it).